# Recent semi co-op maze game designed to be played blind

Tags: identify-this-game

I saw a game recently appear on my personal twitter but forgot to fave it and now I cant't find it so might have been deleted.

I think its a fairly new game that is a semi co-op,  All players against one other.  Player are trying to escape a maze whilst the other player is trying the hunt them down.

What made the game look interested was the fact players except the hunter had to wear blackout glasses and we unable to see.  I believe there was a story about the designer trying to come with a game design playable by a blind relative?

The board looked plain black with many squares.  Between them were what looked like white/glow in the dark wall pieces.  These all had rough looking spiky tops.

That all I can remember and cant recall the title.  I was wanting to read rules and see how a game played blind would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game is [Nyctophobia](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/249505/nyctophobia). I spoke with the designer last weekend, and she said it's scheduled for a Gencon 2018 release.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to find!  No wonder I couldn't recall the title!  Shame the rules aren't on the BGG link, really interested to see how the mechanics for this will work.

Comment: I played it a year ago, but can't really remember specifics - except that the one "sighted" person guides the blind players' hands to the pieces when they take their turns.